# Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'rawPointer'

Tags: hex, swift5, xcode11, mac-address

```
   extension NSData {

    func hexString() -> String {
        return UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes), count: length)
            .reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) }
    }

}
```

Since Xcode 11 getting the Mac address from hex in swift is just making me loopy. I was told this was a good way to do it, but all I get are errors.

I get the MAC address incased in a string from a Ble device connecting to iOS , of course in 11, 12 and under I get the Mac address in the format I need.

I get the Mac address like this from the Ble device.   `<hexvalue>` 
I have code that removes the < and > that works, but ever since the updates Apple did, I know get this as an example : `"{length = 6, bytes = 0x686578636172}\n`

How do I just simply remove the extra crap now? all I need is the hex. I can convert that to the Mac by inserting :, that's easy. debugDescription doesn't work.  .description doesn't work and I understand it was never intended to be used that way, but I am plopped into a code base that uses it like that in a lot of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
import Foundation
extension Data {
    func hexString() -> String {
        self.compactMap {
            String(format: "%02x", $0)
        }.joined()
    }
}

var data = Data("Hello World".utf8)
data.append(contentsOf: [1,2,3,4,5])
print(data.hexString())
```

prints

```
48656c6c6f20576f726c640102030405
```

or even better

```
import Foundation
extension Data {
    var hexString: String {
        self.compactMap {
            String(format: "%02x", $0)
        }.joined()
    }
}

var data = Data("Hello World".utf8)
data.append(contentsOf: [1,2,3,4,5])
print(data.hexString)
```